# Replace string with backslash

Tags: linux, sed

I have some XML files in a folder and I want to replace the path defined inside the files with a different one, so the original file contains:

```
<Ruta MIMEType="application/pdf">\\srvfsrvivwsk02.preprod.corp\SDD\Cap_Incoming\example.pdf</Ruta>
```

And the result should be:

```
<Ruta MIMEType="application/pdf">\\srvfsrvivwsk35.preprod.corp\SDD2\Cap2_Incoming\Incoming2\example.pdf</Ruta>
```

Im trying using the following command but it is not working:

```
a='\\srvfsrvivwsk02.preprod.corp\SDD\Cap_Incoming'
b='\\srvfsrvivwsk35.preprod.corp\SDD2\Cap2_Incoming\Incoming2'

sed -i 's/'$a'/'$b'/g' exaple.xml
```

It seems the backslashes don't work as expected. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be done in a linux script and scheduled because files will be arriving every day

Answer (score 0):

Backslash will escape the following character so you can use two backslashes `\\` to match each `\`

`sed 's/\\\\srvfsrvivwsk02.preprod.corp\\SDD\\Cap_Incoming/\\\\srvfsrvivwsk35.preprod.corp\\SDD2\\Cap2_Incoming\\Incoming2/g' example.xml`                                                            │

Comment: It worked fine but now i need to use the variables:
originalPath=\\\\srvfsrvivwsk02.preprod.corp\\SDD\\Cap_Incoming
targetPath=\\\\srvfsrvivwsk35.preprod.corp\\SDD2\\Cap2_Incoming\\Incoming2
Any ideas?

sed 's/$originalPath/$targetPath/g' example.xml